# How can I select all rows that are even, but not hidden?

Tags: jquery

I want to alternate the background-color of rows.

I'm trying to select `<td>` elements of even rows that are not hidden.

I'm trying the following:

```
$(".results-table tr:not(.hidden-row):even")
    .children("td")
    .css("background-color", "#f1f5f9");
```

but it's not working. I guess I can't use 2 selectors the way I am. Can someone suggest how to do this correctly?

Comment: Yes you can. jQuery is pretty powerful in combining filters together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for that purpose:

```
$(".results-table tr:not(.hidden-row)").filter(":even")
    .children("td").css("background-color", "#f1f5f9");
```

This will also increase performance, since [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) is a jQuery extension, not a native CSS selector.

Comment: Good point about filtering `:even` later to improve performance.

Comment: Excellent! This knowledge has already solved a few other problems for me, and it's not even lunchtime yet! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter`.

```
$(".results-table tr:even").filter(function() { return ! $(this).hasClass('hidden-row'); })
    .children("td")
    .css("background-color", "#f1f5f9");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("results-table tr:not(.hidden-row)").filter(":even")
```